# Google and Facebook sign in conflict (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement sign in with facebook and google in php.
They work perfectly separatly and there is no problems.

But when I try them together,it looks like facebook api try to connect with google authentication.

Exactly when i click on the facebook sign in, i have this error:

***Fatal error:**

### Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in /Myfolder/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/google/vendor/google/api-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:114 Stack trace: #0 /Myfolder/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/google/vendor/google/api-client/src/Google_Client.php(131): Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, 'AQfjtxTYMHMZmEz...') #1 /Myfolder/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/classes/GoogleAuth.php(36): Google_Client->authenticate('AQfjtxTYMHMZmEz...') #2 /Myfolder/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/login.php(9): GoogleAuth->checkRedirectCode() #3 {main} thrown in /Myfolder/MAMP/htdocs/My_app/google/vendor/google/api-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 114

*
So i don't find a way to make work the facebook sign in without conflict with the checkRedirectCode() function for the goole api.

Has anyone had this problem or knows how to do?

Comment: I don't think fb api would, by design, try login in Google authentication. The problem would most probably be you gluing code in-between. You need to reveal more of your code so anyone could give you answer.

Comment: It's exactly what i thought at the first time but when i comment all the lines where i include the process for google api every things works nicely without this error.

Comment: The problem is the session, i don't find a way to use one "session start" to make work fb api if the user click on it or google api...[edit] I finaly resolve the problem using ajax "onclick" to start the script in the facebook button and it's working now with one "session start()" include where i begin the google api process... I'm not really understanding how it can work lol if someone can bring some knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted something yesterday but it wasn't a real answer so got deleted! Sorry for that guys.

Just as a background explanation, Adam here uses the facebook and google logins of the tutorial phpacademy. Since I use the same I know what he is talking about.

Allright!!!
So.......! Put both (google and fb) URIs to be the same target and try this:
in GoogleAuth class in its function checkRedirectCode() add this check before calling the function:

```
public function checkRedirectCode()    {
if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook'])) {
            if(isset($_GET['code']))
            {
                BLABLABLABLABLA
                }

                return true;

            }
                return false;
        } else {
            //skip this
            echo "FB session on";
        }
}
```

It worked for me, let me know if it does for you.
Basically you don't want to call that function if facebook is logged in! :)